# Request for user IP adress returns server ip address

Tags: php, ip, server

When I'm trying to obtain user IP address `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` it returns me server IP address instead. I'm using PHP in Apache.

What problem it could be? I'm using own VPS from digitalocean with LAMP in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Try using the code given here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php

Comment: Tried it before creating question

Comment: Are you visiting the page with the same server? If not u must contact server administrator

Comment: fixed. changed `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/remoteip.conf` "remoteip mod"

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am eating my words now.

This is interesting.

Let try another:

```
<?php
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

I am stumped, I will think about it.  I have posted my phpinfo and yours.
 Yours should also have 99.3.150.55 for `_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

[image]

[image]

No, I highly doubt what you are saying is true.  You are overlooking something.

If you are willing to give me a link, put this script on your Server:

I would like to go to that link and see your Servers IP address come up when I visit.

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ;  
?>
```

Comment: Ok, try to go through the same url.

Comment: So you don't know where the problem is, true? Becouse this thing with IP address messed me up so hard..

Comment: Not at all, I could not believe it.  That is why I posted the pics as I am sure others will not believe it.  I also up voted you to get rid of the minus.

Comment: Ok. So the unnamed force is displaying user IP as server IP. Should I look the server side problem? And I'm not sure whe the problem should stand off.

Comment: Must be a bug, the latest stable version is PHP 5.6.7, you may want to try a newer version.